# Wordpress PHP get_results unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am receiving a unexpected t_string when trying to use this function I made. I know I must be missing something here.

```
function get_top_terms(){
global $wpdb;
$termsSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT AN_terms.name from AN_posts INNER JOIN AN_term_relationships on AN_term_relationships.object_id = AN_posts.ID INNER JOIN AN_term_taxonomy on AN_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=AN_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN AN_terms on AN_term_taxonomy.term_id=AN_terms.term_id where AN_posts.post_date_gmt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and AN_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag" group by AN_terms.name order by count DESC limit 5";
$tResults = $wpdb->get_results($termsSQL);
print_r($tResults);
}
add_shortcode ( 'topTerms', 'get_top_terms');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
function get_top_terms(){
global $wpdb;
$termsSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT AN_terms.name from AN_posts INNER JOIN AN_term_relationships on AN_term_relationships.object_id = AN_posts.ID INNER JOIN AN_term_taxonomy on AN_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=AN_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN AN_terms on AN_term_taxonomy.term_id=AN_terms.term_id where AN_posts.post_date_gmt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and AN_term_taxonomy.taxonomy ='post_tag' group by AN_terms.name order by count DESC limit 5";
$tResults = $wpdb->get_results($termsSQL);
print_r($tResults);
}

add_shortcode ( 'topTerms', 'get_top_terms');
```

a simple syntax error appears.

I just changed the 'post_tag' part

Comment: That clears that error. Now I have to figure out why adding this to functions.php creates an error on the site

Comment: In general, even a small syntax error will cancel the entire site.